# Unable To Run IPython nbconvert From Python2.7 Virtual Environment

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, fabric, nbconvert

I have a virtual environment of **Python 2.7** with **ipython** installed (Ubuntu 16.04.2 (Xenial) LTS.)

When I’m working in the virtual environment (after running `source venv/bin/activate` in *bash* shell while being in the parent directory of the virtual environment) I have no problem executing conversion of my jupiter’s notebook from **bash** shell like so:

```
ipython nbconvert --to html --execute my_notes.ipynb --stdout > /tmp/report.html
```

But when I’m trying to call that command from fabric’s task using `subprocess`:

```py
command = ['ipython', 'nbconvert', '--to', 'html', '--execute', notebook_path, '--stdout']
output = subprocess.check_output(command,
                                 cwd=os.environ['PYTHONPATH'],
                                 env=os.environ.copy())
```

It always fails with this exception I cannot find a reason for it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/backend/venv/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/opt/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/opt/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/opt/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/opt/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/opt/backend/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py", line 59, in <module>
    class Pdb(bdb.Bdb, cmd.Cmd):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cmd'
```

*More info to save your time.*

I’ve tried:

- Using same paths for **PYTHONPATH** as I got from PyCharm run/debug configuration.
- Using *nbconvert* as python library [from this documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbconvert_library.html).
- Tried `os.system("ipython nbconvert…")`.
- Wrapped working command (`ipython nbconvert…`) with a shell script and used it in `subprocess.check_output` and `os.system`.
- Get drunk and bang my head on a brick wall.

And always end-up with that cursed exception.

Comment: Is there a file called `cmd.py` around somewhere?

Comment: Oh my! Yes indeed! Moving it out of project solves the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer for completeness:

There was a file called `cmd.py` somewhere where Python was finding it as an importable module. This was shadowing the [cmd module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) in the standard library, which is used by pdb, which IPython imports. When pdb tried to subclass a class from `cmd`, that class wasn't there. Moving `cmd.py` out of the way lets it find the cmd module it needs.

This is an unfortunate annoyance with Python - lots of short words are already used as module names, and using them yourself produces crashes, with a wide range of different errors.